# Javascript create arrays of time pairs every half hour

Tags: javascript

i should generate an array of strings that maps time pairs to me every half hour, starting from a departure time like 1pm and an end time like 11pm, that i can dynamically create an array of this type:

```
return ['13: 00-13: 30 ',' 13: 30-14: 00 ',' 14: 00-14: 30 ',' 14: 30-15: 00 ',' 15: 00-15: 30 ', '20: 00-20: 30', '20: 30-21: 00', '21: 00-21: 30', '21: 30-22: 00', '22: 00-22: 30 ']
```

I had found an approach but was unable to adapt it to my needs:

```
function getTimes(start, end) {
    start = parseInt(start) * 2 + (+start.slice(-2) > 0);
    end = parseInt(end) * 2 + (+end.slice(-2) > 0) + 1;
    return Array.from({length: end - start}, (_, i) =>
        (((i + start) >> 1) + ":" + ((i + start)%2*3) + "0").replace(/^\d:/, "0$&"));
};
console.log(getTimes("13:00", "24:00"));
```

I get an output like this, which is not good:

```
[ '13:00',
  '13:30',
  '14:00',
  '14:30',
  '15:00',
  '15:30',
  '16:00',
  '16:30',
  '17:00',
  '17:30',
  '18:00',
  '18:30',
  '19:00',
  '19:30',
  '20:00',
  '20:30',
  '21:00',
  '21:30',
  '22:00',
  '22:30',
  '23:00',
  '23:30',
  '24:00' ]
```

Comment: create a function which combines pairs?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just track everything in minutes, with two helpers for conversion between strings and minutes:

```js
function parseTime(timeString) {
  let time = timeString.split(":");
  return time[0] * 60 + time[1] * 1;
}

function timeString(time) {
  let h = Math.floor(time / 60);
  if (h > 23) h -= 24;
  let m = time % 60;
  return h.toString().padStart(2, "0") + ":" + m.toString().padStart(2, "0");
}

function getTimes(start, end) {
  start = parseTime(start);
  end = parseTime(end);
  if (end < start) end += 24 * 60;
  let result = [];
  while (start < end) {
    result.push(timeString(start) + "-" + timeString(start + 30));
    start += 30;
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(getTimes("13:00", "24:00"));
```